# GDI... or equivalent for C++?

Tags: c++, winforms, gdi+, gdi

I'm getting myself all confused, so I thought here would be a great place to ask this question.

What alternatives to GDI/GDI+ do I have if I want to write my own Custom Controls (fully-custom drawn too) in C++?

I've been doing this in VB and C# using GDI for a while, but I'd like to start in C++.

I'd prefer not to use any third party stuff, and instead stick to native. The kind of apps I'll be making I guess you could say are like WinForms apps/GUI-based.

But I don't want to create WinForms apps in C++.

Should I use Direct2D for UI drawing in C++? Or does C++ have GDI? What should I use?

The kinds of controls I'll be creating are:

TextBox, ListView, Switch Control, Progress Indicator... Basically I'll be rewriting all the controls I made in C# in C++ from scratch.

Comment: Direct2D would probably be over-kill for a custom control; is there a reason you don't want to use GDI? If you want to "stick to native" it's really the obvious choice.

Comment: @JonathanPotter A while ago I was told that GDI is a C# thing. And I'd never seen C++ in the same sentence as GDI, so I just believed it without looking. But when I did search for custom drawing in C++, all I saw was DirectWrite Direct2D, etc... If GDI is available, I'll use it. I'm happy with it. What about Direct2D would be overkill? Could you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: GDI is a native Windows API which means it's available in C and C++ (and other languages too). Direct2D is a COM-based API which, while usable from C++, is far more complicated than GDI. Unless you need the performance it can offer which seems unlikely for a control, GDI should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A while ago I was told that GDI is a C# thing

Well no, **GDI predates .NET** and is the default choice for c/c++ and compatible languages. It goes back at least to Windows 3 days (anything earlier to that I have no experience with so I can't comment).

> The Microsoft Windows graphics device interface (GDI) enables applications to use graphics and formatted text on both the video display and the printer. Windows-based applications do not access the graphics hardware directly. Instead, GDI interacts with device drivers on behalf of applications - [More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx)

GDI+ is the *"class-based API for C/C++ programmers"*:

> Windows GDI+ is a class-based API for C/C++ programmers. It enables applications to use graphics and formatted text on both the video display and the printer. Applications based on the Microsoft Win32 API do not access graphics hardware directly. Instead, GDI+ interacts with device drivers on behalf of applications. GDI+ is also supported by Microsoft Win64. [More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx)

OP:

> I want to write my own Custom Controls (fully-custom drawn too) in C++?

Great question. Since you want to create them in c++ and perform fully custom-drawn you have a couple of options.

### Subclassing

This is a really old technique and I'm not sure if anyone bothers anymore.  It was something we did before OLE/ActiveX controls came along.  The idea is to have a control already present and at runtime you *subclass* so that you can effectively take over the look and feel of the control.  The downside is that the container does much of the work and they aren't really that re-usable.

### ActiveX Controls

Originally OLE COM Controls; ActiveX came about around ~1995 when the Internet was taking off and there was a need to make OLE Controls smaller so that web pages loaded quicker.  They're essentially OLE Controls but with many of the unneeded COM interfaces removed that weren't really required for web pages.

ActiveX controls, being COM; are language-neutral and truely reusable unlike subclassing.  You can embed ActiveX into COM-aware containers whether they be c++; Delphi; Visual Objects; VB; Access; web or even .NET WinForms.

**Custom Drawn**

The real nice thing about ActiveX is that you can either create composite controls (controls containing other standard Windows controls) or blank completely-render-able controls where you can use GDI/GDI+ (or anything that can render to a GDI context) allowing you to create a truly beautiful; customised control.

Ever seen those spiffy charts?  Chances are they were ActiveX.

Look into Microsoft ATL c++ class library.  It has some great skeletons for creating COM ActiveX controls and containers.   WTL is also a nice general purpose library which MS released to the public domain if memory serves.

### Direct2D

> Should I use Direct2D for UI drawing in C++? Or does C++ have GDI? What should I use?

Unless you have a particular need for hardware acceleration, using Direct2D takes you down a certain path you may not want - such as setting up a Direct2D environment in your app, on a computer that supports Direct2D.  However, if you are interested [here is a nice article on D2D-GDI interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370971(v=vs.85).aspx)

I'd stick with GDI/GDI+.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Irrlicht: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/

It's technically a gaming engine but I have used it in many projects for simple 2D UI drawing. The learning curve is also extremely gentle.

Anyways it has all of the controls you're asking about but enables you to write your own if you choose.